# Fast splitting huge .csv onto disk with python

Tags: python, csv, bigdata

I have a .csv file of about 100 GB and want to split it into 1 GB files with python 3.5.4 (for the record :) ).

I have written the function `split_csv('filename.csv')` below.

My question is how can I make it faster. That is needed, because I will be regularly splitting new versions of the huge .csv file.

Notes (contain edits):

- I want to do it on disk. It cannot fit into RAM.
- The 1GB .csv files should be split where the line ends. So they will be "about" 1GB. Not exactly.

  import os
  import pandas as pd
  import csv
  import time

  def split_csv(file,filesize=1000, header='T'):
      start = time.time()

  ```
  with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf8', newline='') as infile:
      datareader = csv.reader(infile)

      outfile_iterator=100001
      outfilename = file.split('.')[0]
      outfilename = outfilename+'_'+str(outfile_iterator)+'.csv'
      o = open(outfilename, 'w',newline='')
      outfile = csv.writer(o, delimiter=',', lineterminator="\r\n")
      print('writing to ',outfilename)

      total_row_count=0
      row_count = 0
      for row in datareader:
          if header=='T' and total_row_count==0:
              header_row=row
              print('header: ',header_row)
          outfile.writerow(row)
          row_count = row_count + 1
          total_row_count=total_row_count+1
          if os.stat(outfilename).st_size > (filesize*1048576) :
              print('rowcount: ',row_count)
              row_count = 0
              o.close()
              outfile_iterator = outfile_iterator + 1
              outfilename = file.split('.')[0]
              outfilename = outfilename+'_'+str(outfile_iterator)+'.csv'
              o = open(outfilename, 'w',newline='')
              outfile = csv.writer(o, delimiter=',', lineterminator="\r\n")
              print('writing to ',outfilename)
              if header=='T':
                  outfile.writerow(header_row)
                  print('header: ',header_row)

  print('rowcount: ',row_count)
  infile.close()
  o.close()

  elapsed = (time.time() - start)
  print(elapsed, " seconds")
  ```

Comment: You can't do that much faster. The bottleneck here is I/O speed limitations.

Answer (score -1):

Using `file.read(size)` will read `size` bytes from your file.

Using `file.readline()` will read only a line from your file without loading the whole file.

If you want to create only 1GB chunks then use the first one.

If you want to create about 1GB sized .csv files then use the second one and count the size of the output file at each write.

Comment: Good remark. I need each csv file to end where the record line ends. So, "about" 1GB. Will the file.readline() be faster than the reader I am using in the code sample?

Comment: The OP (correctly) states they want to split the CSV file at valid points (line ends). There is no reason to suggest using `read` since it will most likely make the file invalid.